# Class App\Http\middleware\noCache does not exist Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel-5, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

Al cargar el proyecto de laravel en ubuntu server mediante una instancia de Google Cloud, me tira este error:

```
ReflectionException thrown with message "Class App\Http\middleware\noCache does not exist"
```

Stacktrace:

```
#7 ReflectionException in /var/www/html/gaztierradentro/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:790
#6 ReflectionClass:__construct in /var/www/html/gaztierradentro/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:790
#5 Illuminate\Container\Container:build in /var/www/html/gaztierradentro/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:667
#4 Illuminate\Container\Container:resolve in /var/www/html/gaztierradentro/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:615
#3 Illuminate\Container\Container:make in /var/www/html/gaztierradentro/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php:757
#2 Illuminate\Foundation\Application:make in /var/www/html/gaztierradentro/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:215
#1 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:terminateMiddleware in /var/www/html/gaztierradentro/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php:189
#0 Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel:terminate in /var/www/html/gaztierradentro/public/index.php:60
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resulto que en

```
app/Http/kernel.php
```

dentro de

```
/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'authorize' => \App\Http\middleware\authorize::class,
    'noCache' => \App\Http\middleware\noCache::class,
];
```

había que cambiar dentro de los llamados "middleware" por "Middleware", así:

```
     /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'authorize' => \App\Http\Middleware\authorize::class,
        'noCache' => \App\Http\Middleware\noCache::class,
    ];
```